# Booting ubuntu / pop os through a liveUSB creates a strange flickering pattern on the display

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I've had this computer I put together four years ago, and it worked as it was supposed to. I need to reuse it now, so I got a new SSD and ubuntu / popOs on a liveUSB to try and install it. With both distributions I got the following problems:

- Firstly, I noticed that I'm unable to use the VGA input with any of my LCDs. I need to use the HDMI for it to work else I get "Invalid format" (even for BIOS). My LCDs are perfectly fine and regular and this didn't happen before.
- Secondly, and majorly, I get the following screens https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvkZF.jpg (through a projector I have since I'm using the HDMI port)

So, the first part of the boot process works as expected, booting up from the liveUSB, with loading, loading descriptions and animations. Then, some screen tearing starts and afterwards that full pattern emerges, not static, flickering and "rendering" constantly, with what seem to be system restarts.

I'm stuck in this and can't find any way to fix it.

Screens:

First: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agCzP.png

Second: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEcIb.png

Third: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M52y.png

Specs:

- AM1l motherboard
- One Kingston RAM stick (around 2 or 4 gb)
- A N13219 ASUS 128MB video card, or analogue
- I don't remember the CPU but it hasn't been removed since the computer was put away (working fine at the time). Most probably AMD.

Any idea? I've been scratching my head on how this can be troubleshooted. Google has been of no help. Thank you.

Comment: "the first part of the boot process works as expected, ... Then, some screen tearing starts "  <--- Did you try updating BIOS?  If you can boot from any USB, update the Video driver.

Comment: @John with that sentence I mean the computer boots up until the "Second" picture I took. Until then there's a loading bar, "Ubuntu", that circle logo, all working, but I can't even get to a prompt or login or whatever.